# Transport initialization error in Eclipse (Trying to update plugin)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to update the Android ADT in Eclipse

Help -> Check for updates

This gives me the following error message:
http://cl.ly/3Z1O3h1e3A1b2F3v091D

As you can see by the error message, I even tried updating by a zip file, this also gives me the: 
**Transport initialization error.**

There aren't any problems with my connection as I can load webpages in the internal browser in Eclipse. I get the same error message either if I am trying to update with an archive file or directly via internet...

Here's the error message in text:

```
Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
Unable to read repository at jar:file:/C:/Users/njaal/Downloads/ADT-18.0.0.zip!/content.xml.
Transport initialization error.
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Transport initialization error.
```

Edit: This is under windows 7 64 bit, Eclipse Indigo (for Java Developers)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about the root cause, but the suggestion to **run Eclipse as Administrator** solved the problem for me.

[image]

Stolen from [Eclipse Update Failing with Message "Insufficient access privileges to apply this update"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963884/eclipse-update-failing-with-message-insufficient-access-privileges-to-apply-thi)